# React, Material Ui, Emoji slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image][image]
I'm new to react I have been struggling to come up with that functionality shown in the attached pic, I have managed to implement the emoji slider with different facial expressions, Still cannot implement these different and synchronized moods with the change of every picked up emoji

**the new modification is that I need to use customized SVG Emoji instead of the pre-created standard ones . how can I approach that design ??

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";


export default function Emoji() {
  const [mood, setMood] = useState(null);

  function handleChange(e)
  {
    const val = e.target.value;
    {if (val < 25) {
      setMood("");
      Router
    } else if (val >= 25 && val < 50) {
      setMood("");
    } else if (val  >= 50 && val < 70) {
      setMood("");
    } else if (val >= 75 && val < 90 ) {
      setMood("");
    } else if (val > 90) {
      setMood("");
    }
  }}


  return (
    <div className="emoji">
        <div style={{position: "relative", bottom: "-90px", fontSize: "100px",transition: "ease-in-out",  }}>
        <input style={{  width: "-webkit-fill-available",}}  type="range" list="tickmarks" onChange={handleChange}  />

        </div>
      <datalist id="tickmarks">
        <option value="preserving face" label=""></option>
        <option value="pensive face" label=""></option>
        <option value="expressionless face" label=""></option>
        <option value="slightly smiling face" label=""></option>
        <option value="grinning face with big eyes" label=""></option>
      </datalist>

      <p style={{position: "relative", bottom: "108px", fontSize: "70px" }}>{mood}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

.

please any help and support will be much appreciated !!

Comment: Can you provide your current implementation where we can approach your issue ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, please be advised that I have updated the question with code snippet of the JSx file  @ 
Kavindu VIndika

Comment: @KavinduVIndika

Comment: nice I'll take a look

Comment: Sorry for late replies because of busy day yesterday. It feels like you've already implemented the emoji slider, but what you want to do is to have a smooth change between each emoji right ? Or is it something else ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Can you please explain this **different and synchronized moods with the change of every picked up emoji** ? Your implementation is perfectly fine, I just did some error corrections in your code and edited it. Other than that emoji slider is working fine.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika, i have added another detailed picture of the current design. what I need to implement is whenever an emoji is being picked up it should have another shown described mood to indicate the user feeling along with the chosen facial expression !, hope that the attached picture is kind beneficial

Comment: you are awesome , thanks a lot for your tremendous help

Comment: I did some updates in `gridContainerStyles` and `gridItemStyles`. Please use it to avoid any errors or warnings. And if it solve your issue, please kindly accept it as the answer and upvote.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika, please would you mind having a look at the new task regarding that design , as I have been asked to implement a customized SVG emoji instead of the predefined emojis -- already got the Icon sets for the attached picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to keep all the details necessary for the selected mood inside the state (In addition to the mood that you're displaying). Therefore, storing complete object having mood display and mood features (e.g. - sad, anxious etc.) inside the state is the best possible way to tackle this issue.

Use the following example as a supportive resource to solve your issue.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const moodDetails = {
  mood0: {
    display: "",
    details: ["Sad", "Stressed", "Anxious"],
  },
  mood1: {
    display: "",
    details: ["Sad", "Stressed", "Anxious"],
  },
  mood2: {
    display: "",
    details: ["Indifferent", "Board", "Numb"],
  },
  mood3: {
    display: "",
    details: ["Happy", "Relaxed", "Satisfied"],
  },
  mood4: {
    display: "",
    details: ["Happy", "Relaxed", "Satisfied"],
  },
};

const gridContainerStyles = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "auto auto auto",
  backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  padding: "10px",
};
const gridItemStyles = {
  backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
  border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
  padding: "20px",
  fontSize: "30px",
  textAlign: "center",
};

export default function Emoji() {
  const [mood, setMood] = useState({});

  function handleChange(e) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (val < 25) {
      setMood(moodDetails.mood0);
    } else if (val >= 25 && val < 50) {
      setMood(moodDetails.mood1);
    } else if (val >= 50 && val < 70) {
      setMood(moodDetails.mood2);
    } else if (val >= 75 && val < 90) {
      setMood(moodDetails.mood3);
    } else if (val > 90) {
      setMood(moodDetails.mood4);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="emoji">
        <div
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            bottom: "-90px",
            fontSize: "100px",
            transition: "ease-in-out",
          }}
        >
          <input
            style={{ width: "-webkit-fill-available" }}
            type="range"
            list="tickmarks"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <datalist id="tickmarks">
          <option value="preserving face" label=""></option>
          <option value="pensive face" label=""></option>
          <option value="expressionless face" label=""></option>
          <option value="slightly smiling face" label=""></option>
          <option value="grinning face with big eyes" label=""></option>
        </datalist>

        <p style={{ position: "relative", bottom: "108px", fontSize: "70px" }}>
          {mood.display}
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2>How would you describe your mood ?</h2>
      <div style={gridContainerStyles}>
        {mood.details?.map((detail) => (
          <div style={gridItemStyles}>{detail}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Component view**

[image]

In-line styling used to decorate the component when showing features. (Better to use antd, material-ui libraries for styling in order to achieve a better view)

`mood.details?.map` is used to map jsx elements dynamically.

Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for your interest in helping me , however, I got a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, when trying to render the modified component!. if it does work on your end, May I ask you how did you solve it !?

Again your help is quite appreciated

Comment: It happens because I forgot to put optional chaining for `mood.details?.map`. Initial state `{}` doesn't contain a `details` object inside it. Therefore, `mood.details` will be undefined at the initial rendering. As a results `map` function going to fail with above error as you had. I updated the answer. Please check whether it works.

Comment: If optional chaining not working, then please use this for the initial state `const [mood, setMood] = useState({
    display: null,
    details: [],
  });`